# one of two HC-06 bluetooth modules only can be detected

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, iot

i am working on a device for my project that needs two HC-06 bluetooth modules to be connected to the pc. both of the modules are ok to be connected separately and are working fine. but when both of them are powered at the same time, the pc detect only on of them. **are they getting the same address?**

Answer (score 0):

No. PC should be able to detect both the devices, if two HC-06 modules are in discoverable state. Each Bluetooth device has a unique ID, so every bluetooth unit has a unique address.

Based on your question, I think the app is trying to connect to first device it finds.

Comment: i totally understand that every Bluetooth module have a unique id. but in my situation, from the last package we bought in the lab, i have tested 10 modules of HC-06 powered at the same time and they overlap  eachothers. comparing with modules from different packages, it was ok to detect more than one module.